# ng add @nebular/theme - ERROR: Cannot find module @angular-devkit/core/src/terminal

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying Nebular for the first time, following the tutorial from their website.
I created a new angular project by installing Angular CLI. This is not my first Angular project, and Angular seems to work normally.
I then tried to add Nabular with

```
sudo ng add @nebular/theme
```

The installation seems to be working correctly but then I get:

```sh
    Cannot find module @angular-devkit/core/src/terminal

Require stack:
- node_modules/@nebular/theme/schematics/ng-add/register-modules/index.js
- node_modules/@nebular/theme/schematics/ng-add/setup.js
- node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- .npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- .npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

I am pretty sure Nebular was NOT installed correctly since the `app.module.ts` was not modified, nor the nebular styles were added in `angular.json`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same bug. It might come from the current version of angular.

I managed to install nebular manually.

Follow the subsection manually:

[Install Nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/install-nebular#manually)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Fixed it perfectly for me!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there is an issue with regard to  `@angular-devkit`
Try the following steps,

Step 1:

```
npm update -g @angular/cli
```

Step 2:

Edit your `package.json` changing the line

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
```

to

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
```

STEP 3:

```
npm update
```

Comment: seems like you copied this answer from a question made long time ago. Right now angular CLI version is like 11.0, I don't see any reason to install the 1.6. Also this solution doesn't work anyway